# Term-Document payload support in Lucene

Tags: lucene, codec, payload

I am using Elasticsearch 1.3.4 and as a result Lucene 4.9. I have a requirement of storing some information per term-document pair (something like term frequency but only spanning variable number of bytes). I am aware of payloads being supported by Lucene, but that information is per term-document-occurrence trio. Hence in my case, it would be an overkill to use payloads. Well, I can also try saving that information as a payload corresponding to only the first occurrence of a term in a document but that does not sound very clean.

I would like to know if there is an out of the box solution for storing term-document custom information in Lucene. If not, what are my alternatives?